# How to append to the existing file in git

Tags: git

I have a git repo and for deployment we need to create new files and we need to append some files. I am trying to automate it using shell script.

**4 files need to be created and 3 files need to be modified.**
From file change and creation aside, everything is working.
But there is problem with `git add`.
When I use `git add` for the new files which need to be created, it is working fine and the file is getting created. 
But for appending files, it is not working. The contents are not appending to the existing file

I wrote a script and this is the flow:

```
cd tf-infra
git checkout -b test2
git status
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse master
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
git remote --verbose

#code change

git status
git add modules/xxx  # new file needs to be added
git add modules/yyy  # new file needs to be added
git add modules/zzz  # new file needs to be added
git add modules/aaa  # new file needs to be added
git add aws-qa/ccc   # new file needs to be modified
git add modules/bbb  # new file needs to be modified
git add modules/ddd  # new file needs to be modified


git commit -m "test2 Final"
git push origin test2
```

When I run the above script, new files are getting created but appending is not happening.

Please help me in appending the contents to the existing file

Kindly help!

Comment: So, you are sure that `ccc` has been changed, but after you do a `git add` on it, it is not shown in the staging area? I would put a `git status` just before you do the commit. Also, I would do a `git diff aws-qa/ccc` before doing the add, and maybe a `git diff --cached aws-qa/ccc` after the add, to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @user1934428 pointed out, the files might've actually not got appended. Doing a `git add` on them unnecessarily won't have any effect on them and also won't throw an error of any kind.

Most probably, the problem would be with the shell script you have created. You may want to check it once again. This isn't a problem with `git add`.

Also, an advice for you, don't give out your e-mail just like that in public. BTW, `git remote --verbose` is the same as `git remote -v`, so this will save you some time.

Best.